# javascript regex match between two strings and count the number of characters inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, for-loop

I'm very new to js and programming, and i'd appreciate some help.

Suppose I have the following array (It is a single element array, they are not seperate elements)

```
var array =
[
     'Foo\n' +
      'bar23123\n' +
      'barbarfoo\n' +
      'foo, bar foo\n' +
      'foo\n' +
      '\n' +
      '\n' +
      'Bar\n' +
      '\n' +
      '\n'
  ]
```

Assuming there are multiple elements in the array, how can I write a regex expression to count and match the number of literal '\n' in between Foo\n and Bar\n in each element.

I wrote a partial solution to iterate through and return the count of all \n but how do I narrow my search to only return the values in between the two strings?

Here is the code:

```
let slashN = [];
for(let slash of array){
   var reg = RegExp('\\n' , 'g')
  slashN.push(slash.match(reg).length)
}

console.log(slashN);
```

I get the correct count, but I want to refine the regex expression.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean `var reg = /(?<=Foo.*?)\n(?=.*?Bar)/gs;`?

Comment: In this case, I'd want it to return a value of 6. (it takes the \n after 'bar23123' 'barbarfoo' 'foo, bar foo' 'foo' and then '\n' and '\n'. Yours seems to return 7.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think this is the solution:  `var reg = /(?<=Foo\n.*?)\n(?=.*?Bar\n)/gs;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
var reg = /(?<=Foo\n.*?)\n(?=.*?Bar\n)/gs;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oC5UCK/1). **Details**:

- `(?<=Foo\n.*?)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `Foo` + newline and then any 0 or more chars, as few as possible
- `\n` - a newline
- `(?=.*?Bar\n)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with any 0+ chars as few as possible and then `Bar` + newline.

JavaScript demo:

```js
var array =
[
     'Foo\n' +
      'bar23123\n' +
      'barbarfoo\n' +
      'foo, bar foo\n' +
      'foo\n' +
      '\n' +
      '\n' +
      'Bar\n' +
      '\n' +
      '\n'
];
let slashN = [];
for(let slash of array){
  var reg = /(?<=Foo\n.*?)\n(?=.*?Bar\n)/gs;
  slashN.push(slash.match(reg).length)
}

console.log(slashN);
```